# What sdk version of iPhone app should I use? 4.2 or 3.?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Should I be developing my app for 4.2?

Comment: BTW, you've asked 16 questions already but have only accepted answers to 25% of them. Please accept more answers to reward the people who've helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use the latest SDK. Apple won't approve any apps built against 3.x anymore.

**Edit:**

There's a difference between the base SDK and the iOS you plan to support. You need to use the latest SDK as I stated before, however you may still create an app that runs on older versions of iOS by not using classes and methods that have been introduced in newer releases and setting the target OS appropriately.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. So, +1 and I deleted my answer.

Comment: To the extent that it helps the original poster, go to the 'Build' tab of your Target Info, and check out the options 'Base SDK' and 'iOS Deployment Target'. Apple's advice is always to leave the former set to the latest thing (or 'Latest iOS' in recent versions of Xcode), set the latter according to the minimum iOS you want to support — and be sure to test your application on a suitable device.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have the need to support older iOS devices with older iOS versions, you should develop using 4.2 as it has a lot of features that are missing in 3.x. Most importantly: 3.x doesn't support multitasking.

Also, it's important to understand the relationship between [Base SDK version and deployment target](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/base-sdk-and-iphone-os-deployment-target-developing-apps-with-the-4-x-sdk-deploying-to-3-x-devices.html). In a nutshell: you can (and should) compile against the latest SDK version but if done correctly, you can still run the app on older iOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

The base SDK should always be the latest version available (4.2 as of right now). Then you can use the deployment target to specify the minimum OS that your application will support, so a good rule of the thumb would be to use 3.0 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use some of new iOS 4.0 stuff (ie. GCD) a lot in my applications. I've heard that 90% of ios users are on 4.x. That should be a good middle ground.